# javascript converter price undefined

Tags: javascript, converters

I am having trouble finishing this javascript to convert coffee prices..

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Coffee House</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var drink, ounces, price;
prompt ( "Enter the drink type: espresso, latte, cappuccino, americano" );
prompt ( "Enter the oz: 8, 12, 16" )
var shots = prompt ( "Enter the number of shots" )
if ( drink == "espresso")
price = 1.40;
if (( drink == "latte") || (drink == "cappuccino" ))
{
if ( ounce == 8 )
price = 1.95;
else if ( ounce == 12 )
price = 2.35;
else if ( ounce == 16 )
price = 2.75;
}
if ( drink == "americano" )
price = 1.20 + ( ( (ounce -8)/8 ) * .30 );
price = price + ( (shots) * .50 );
price = "price" * 1.055;
price = Math.round( price * 100 )/100;
alert( "Your " + ounce + "oz. " + drink + "with " + shots + "shots of espresso costs: $ " +price );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks man, but it still says ounce is undefined..what should i change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the JavaScript after all the errors have been removed:

```
var drink, ounces, price;
drink = prompt("Enter the drink type: espresso, latte, cappuccino, americano");
ounces = parseInt(prompt("Enter the oz: 8, 12, 16"));
var shots = parseFloat(prompt("Enter the number of shots"));
if (drink === "espresso") price = 1.40;
if ((drink === "latte") || (drink === "cappuccino")) {
  if (ounces === 8) price = 1.95;
  else if (ounces === 12) price = 2.35;
  else if (ounces === 16) price = 2.75;
}
if (drink === "americano") price = 1.20 + ((ounces - 8) / 8) * 0.30;
price = price + shots * 0.50;
price = price * 1.055;
price = Math.round(price * 100) / 100;
alert("Your " + ounces + "oz. " + drink + "with " + shots + "shots of espresso costs: $ " + price);
```

Comment: thank you..that worked except at the end it says price=NaN..what does that mean?

Comment: @user1371539: `NaN` means "not a number". Somewhere you tried to use some mathematical operation on something not a number. (probably a number in string form)

Comment: Well, I owe http://jsbeautifier.org/ and http://www.jshint.com/ some of the credit.

Comment: sweet ill have to check them out I have an extra credit java script coming up about integers 1-10 being squared, cubed, and quad